# Travis CI build number for each branch

Tags: travis-ci, git-branch, semantic-versioning

I have Android app located in GitHub repo connected to Travis CI,
and I have a few branches e.g. master for production, dev for development, qa for testing, etc.

I'd like to include build number as a part of artifact name, e.g.  `0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.53` for development or `0.2.0-RC.12` for testing.

Obviously Travis CI build number should be unique for different branches. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The `TRAVIS_BRANCH` and `TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER` environment variables can be used to access those details about the build. Additional information about this can be found in the [Default Environment Variables](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Default-Environment-Variables) section of Travis CI's documentation.

Where and how you use these environment variables will depend on what you need to do but as a general note, they're accessed using the `$TRAVIS_BRANCH` syntax.

Happy to elaborate on anything if needed. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply, but you didn't understand question. I need TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER as a number for build from particular branch, and not general number of builds in the whole repo

Comment: I see. My apologies for misunderstanding. As far as I know there’s no easy/convenient way to do this but it should still be possible (through the API or webhooks or whatever). I’ll do some more research and share my findings.

Comment: Yes, I think it would be useful for everybody who's using SemVer approach. It's important because for dev env we can have dozens of builds every day and only a few staging builds per week. In Jenkins it's BUILD_NUMBER for each job which does exactly what needed.

Comment: I would add that build metadata should be appended as a build meta tag (+buildmeta) if you intend to claim adherence to [SemVer 2.0.0] (https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html), assuming your feed/channel supports that notation.